# Devolver un array de Objetos con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

tengo el siguiente código en PHP:

```
$output = '';

$output .= 'values: [{ ';

$output .= 'arg: "N", ';
$output .= 'val1: '.round($Val1N / $rowCount,2).', '; 
$output .= 'val2: '.round($Val2N / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val3: '.round($Val3N / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val4: '.round($Val4N / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val5: '.round($Val5N / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val6: '.round($Val6N / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val7: '.round($Val7N / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val8: '.round($Val8N / $rowCount,2).' }, {';

$output .= 'arg: "NNE", ';
$output .= 'val1: '.round($Val1NNE / $rowCount,2).', '; 
$output .= 'val2: '.round($Val2NNE / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val3: '.round($Val3NNE / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val4: '.round($Val4NNE / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val5: '.round($Val5NNE / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val6: '.round($Val6NNE / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val7: '.round($Val7NNE / $rowCount,2).', ';
$output .= 'val8: '.round($Val8NNE / $rowCount,2).' }]';

echo json_encode($output);
```

Que me genera unos valores previamente calculados, hasta aquí todo correcto,
el problema viene al devolver con echo este array de Objetos, utilizo ajax con el siguiente código :

```
       $.ajax({
          url:'process.php',
          method:"POST",
          data:{a:a, b:b, c:c},
           success:function(data)
          {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            funcion_cargar(response);
```

El problema viene cuando devuelvo los valores pero utilizando console.info(response) parece que en formato String, en cualquier caso no de la forma que los necesito. Funciona correctamente si creo una variable en la página principal de la siguiente forma:

```
var response = 
[{values: 
[{arg: "N",
val1: 0, 
val2: 0.01,
val3: 0,
val4: 0,
val5: 0,
val6: 0,
val7:0,
val8: 0}, {
arg: "NNE",
val1: 0,
val2: 0.01,
val3: 0,
val4: 0,
val5: 0,
val6: 0,
val7: 0,
val8: 0
}]}];
```

Decir que la función que utiliza los valores en la página principal utiliza los valores de esta forma

```
   funcion_cargar(response){
    ...
    dataSource: response[0].values,
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Cuidado porque aquí: $output .= 'val8: '.round($Val8NNE / $rowCount,2).' }; te falta cerrar la comilla simple: $output .= 'val8: '.round($Val8NNE / $rowCount,2).' }';

Comment: En la petición ajax te falta el datatype: dataType: "json",

Comment: yo me pregunto donde cierra esto `'values: [{ ';` ? donde cierras eso ?

Comment: Gracias, lo de las comillas no es el problema ya que este código sigue hasta 16 sectores si te fijas en N, NNE, NE, ENE así hasta 16 lo que pasa es que lo he recortado para la pregunta.

Comment: Pues te sugiero que edites la pregunta para que el código sea funcional, de otra forma recibirás mil comentarios sobre lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias Sebastián, como he dicho el código es más extenso y lo cierro más abajo pero no lo he puesto en la pregunta por no alargarlo

Comment: El error arrojado es porque si te fijas la estructura del primer output es {values : [] } y la del segundo es { [0]: {values :[]} }, lo que deberías de hacer es quitar "[0]" de response[0].values en tu funcion_cargar()

Comment: SI, Gracias AmigoTaco ya está solucionado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas generando una cadena json, que luego codificas a json. Eso no es lo que quieres. Lo que te interesa es crear un array, y luego codificarlo a json.

Podrias probar algo como:

```
$output = [];
$output['values'][] = [
  'arg' => 'N',
  'val1' => round($Val1N / $rowCount, 2),
  'val2' => round($val2N / $rowCount, 2),
];

$oputput['values'][] = [
  'arg' => 'NNE',
  'val1' => round($Val1NNE / $rowCount, 2),
  'val2' => round($val2NNE / $rowCount, 2),
];
```

Eso es un objeto output, con una etiqueta VALUES que contiene un array de elementos.

y ahora si, eso lo puedes enviar como un json:

```
echo json_encode($output, true);
```

Comment: Gracias Jakala me ha funcionado bien ya obtengo el objeto con un array de elementos. ¿Puedes editar la respuesta y poner el nombre de variable correctamente?. Gracias de nuevo